# Flink to dynamo Sink

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have one use case to have a sink on AWS-DynamoDB from Apache Flink.
The architecture is like do some real-time processing and sink it into DynamoDB.
Is there Sink for Dynamo Available ?

Answer (score 2):

we have developed a sink to DynamoDB, although it has not yet been published on nexus but it's used in a project in production environment.

[streaming-flink-dynamodb-connector](https://github.com/fabricalab/streaming-flink-dynamodb-connector)

Clone the repository and build it with the following command:

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests=true
```

Comment: I am more curious to know how data types are mapped from flink dataType to dynamo Datatypes ?
As Dynamo has lots of restrictions and only few datatypes with respect to flink datatypes